# Why am I getting an "int is not callable" TypeError with this (python) code?

Tags: python

I'm doing Project Euler's problem 30, which is to find the sum of all the numbers that can be written as the sum of fifth powers of their digits. (http://projecteuler.net/problem=30 for more information.)

For some reason, I'm getting an "int is not callable" TypeError when I try to run my attempted solution:

```
def problem30():
    sum = 0
    for n in xrange(20000):
        if sum([((int(x))**5) for x in list(str(n))]) == n:
            sum += n
    sum
```

Why am I getting such an error, and how might I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't name a variable `sum`, it can get mixed up with the function `sum()`

Comment: @Haidro That's exactly what is happening.

Comment: Oh, of course! I feel rather silly now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You named your variable `sum`, and are trying to use it as the built-in function at the same time.

Rename the `sum` identifier that is meant to be the total sum:

```
def problem30():
    total = 0
    for n in xrange(20000):
        if sum(int(x) ** 5 for x in str(n)) == n:
            total += n
    return total
```

I've simplified your expression a little too; most of the parenthesis and lists were surplus.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Foxin: easy mistake to make. You get to recognize the exception soon enough for what usually is the same type of mistake. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly like calling a variable justData and then trying the following:

```
justData = 0
justData(parameterA, parameterB)
# Oops, tried to call a variable as though it wasn't data.
```